# Run random functions n times and store each outcome to vector

Tags: r

I’m looking for some guidance. I have been looking into repeat, replicate and sapply but is seemingly unable to accomplish my goal, which is to run PLE, LE and L n times and store each outcome of Sum to a vector. I have the following lines of code:

```
    ID <- c(1)
    MinP <- c(0.25)
    MLP <- c(0.4)
    MaxP <- c(0.55)
    MinC <- c(1)
    MLC <- c(2)
    MaxC <- c(3)
    
    confidence <- 4

    PLE <- rpert(ID, MinP, MLP, MaxP, shape = confidence)

    LE <- rbinom(ID, size = 1, prob = PLE)

    L <- rpert(ID, MinC, MLC, MaxC, shape = confidence)

    Sum <- sum(LE * L)
```

Since PLE, LE and L is random functions, every run of PLE, LE and L will generate random outcomes and hence, Sum. Would appreciate guidance on how to store each outcome of Sum to a vector.

Comment: `replicate(10,{...your code...})`

Comment: aaa yes. Easy solutions are the best.